# Why is my connection string (SQL) not being accepted server-side but is functional from the client?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an application that runs via a website that connects to an SQL database. When I run the application directly from Visual Studio the connection strings are all accepted and I can login to the SQL server using the string via Microsoft SQL Server Management studio however when the application is ran on the server/web browser the login fails with the below error using the below connection strings;

```
NameOfConnection": "Server=SERVER\\SERVER;Database=database;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=True
```

> 2023-03-01 09:48:17.214 +00:00 [ERR] _NameOfConnection connection
> failed : Cannot open database "database" requested by the login. The
> login failed. Login failed for user 'user'.

I've tried adding the connection strings directly to IIS with no luck. I've also added the Persist Security Info to the connection string and I've created a new connection string and tried that with no luck. Windows and SQL connection is turned on in Microsoft SQL Server Management, it has EXEC permissions and is a db_owner.

I'm absolutely stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server's logs for the true authentication error? If not, you should. If you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to add that error to your post.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked my SQL Server's logs but its not giving me information regarding the specific login error. I am not the SQL admin for the server, would this matter?

Comment: *If* you have the relevant access, and you can't see an error, this would either mean that the logging on failed connections is off (unlikely if I am honest), or the connection isn't reaching that server. The logs are all or nothing, so if you can access them, then you have access. If you're not the admin, then you might want to talk to your DBA for support first.

Comment: Are you sure your `Release` build is not using different `applicationsettings.json` files? Also, when you say you can login to the server via SMSS; is this from the webserver?

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct server and database? Or that the user exists in the production database with this password? The error complains that the login failed, not that the connection string is wrong.

Comment: `SERVER\SERVER` is a named instance. The default instance runs on `SERVER`. Which one did you try in SSMS? Other database server instances can run on the same machine using a different name, eg 
`SERVER\SQLEXPRESS`,  `SERVER\CUSTOMER1`, `SERVER\SomeOtherApp`. Those are completely separate binaries, folders, databases and users. Are you sure you're supposed to connect to a named instance with the same name as the server instead of the default instance on that server?

Comment: I'm speaking with the DBA to see what logs they can provide and if I have a more specific error I will post. I'm using the Release build and applicationsettings.json are the same on server and client. I haven't tried logging into SMSS on the server, I will give that a go and see if it accepts the connection. I'm sure that it is connecting to the correct server as it works on the client with same connection string and works on SMSS via the client. In SMSS I used the SERVER\SERVER and SQL login to connect so the instance name and server name are the same.

Comment: Seems like it's connecting to a different SQL Server instance. Do either your local computer (where you're running Visual Studio) or the IIS web server have a `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file that defines an address for `SERVER`? If you `ping` or `tracert` the server's name from both places do they resolve to the same IP address?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I ran ping from both the local computer and web server and they both came back with the same IP address. The hosts file contains no addresses for the servers.

Comment: In SSMS are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: @Charlieface I am using the SQL Connection String on server and local computer and it logs in with no problems.

Comment: I was asking about SSMS. When you login using SSMS, are you using Windows Authentication, or are you entering a username and password for SQL Authentication?

Comment: @Charlieface For SSMS, I am using the username and password for SQL authentication.

Comment: OK we need to see the full line from the SQL Server error log that starts `Error: 18456, Severity: ...` the `State` value will tell you what the issue is

Comment: @Charlieface so I've managed to find out the problem and it appears it's completely unrelated to what I originally said, the app is using an old connection string and won't change to the new one that i've set in appsettings.json.